# What's the best way to access a MS Access database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access

I need to access some data from an MS Access database and retrieve some data from it using PHP.

I've looked around the web, and found the following line which seems to correctly connect to the database:

```
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:\wamp\www\data\MYDB.mdb");
```

However, I have tried to retrieve some data in the following way:

```
$query = "SELECT pageid FROM pages_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$amount_of_pages = 0;

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0)
  echo "No results found.";
else
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        $amount_of_pages++;
```

And was presented with the following errors:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\wamp\www\data\index.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\data\index.php on line 23
>   No results found.

I don't really understand the connection to the Access database, is there something I should be doing differently?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Never assume a query call worked. You MUST check `mysqli_error()` after each call. If you'd done that, you'd have see the connection call fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use MySQLi with anything other than a MySQL db.  You'll probably need to use an [ODBC connection](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php).

Answer (score 2):

The `mysqli_*` functions are for MySQL databases only, and can't be used for Microsoft Access databases. See [PHP's ODBC documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) for details on how to use these.

Comment: That seems very obvious now you say it. Could you suggest what the alternative might be so I can have a dig around and find out more?

Comment: Well as I said, the working alternative is to use PHP's ODBC functions instead of the MySQLi functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the ODBC documentation is exactly what I was looking for. You and Phoneix both gave me the info I needed. I simply voted his answer as he was quickest to respond.